# Batch file (ForFiles multiple conditional commands for logic)?

Tags: batch-file, command

I am just getting into Bat files. 
I am trying to delete old folders on a network shared drive but skip 2 of the containing folders by name. 
Basically I need to all files that I make daily and always keep 2 old files.

Code that deletes all files that are older than 3 days:

```
PushD "\\****-****\build" &&(
ForFiles /D -3 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE  echo RD @FILE &RD /S @FILE
 ) & PopD
```

And I was thinking something like this: if NOT @FNAME == %name%. I don't totally understand the process, am I able to have two conditions in the forFiles? do I have to have /c before?

```
PushD "\\****-****\build" &&(
ForFiles /D -3 /C "CMD /C if NOT @FNAME == %name% if @ISDIR==TRUE  echo RD @FILE &RD /S @FILE
 ) & PopD
```

I can't seem to get it, would you mind helping me out? 
Thanks!

Comment: Much as I have nostalgia for batch files, they're been around since the DOS days and they're pretty limited. Consider switching to PowerShell. It's a fully-featured language, can interact with almost all parts of the OS and you can even compile custom modules if you want to. Also, it's much more useful knowledge to have going forward as batch files are going to become less and less relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nesting `if` commands in their *then* branches is the way how-to have logical `AND`. Note proper quoting in next code snippet:

```
@ECHO ON >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions
set "name=SO"
set "nam2=SU"
pushd "D:\VB_scripts"
@rem all directories 
ForFiles /D -2 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE echo @FILE"
@rem all directories except "SO" 
ForFiles /D -2 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE if not @FNAME=="""%name%""" echo @FILE"
@rem all directories except "SO" and "SU" 
ForFiles /D -2 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE if not @FNAME=="""%name%""" if not @FNAME=="""%nam2%""" echo @FILE"
popd
@ENDLOCAL
```

**Output**:

```
==>D:\bat\SO\31346676.bat

==>set "name=SO"

==>set "nam2=SU"

==>pushd "D:\VB_scripts"

==>ForFiles /D -2 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE echo @FILE"

"Class Pack"
"Oldies"
"SO"
"SU"
"WMI"

==>ForFiles /D -2 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE if not @FNAME=="""SO""" echo @FILE"

"Class Pack"
"Oldies"
"SU"
"WMI"

==>ForFiles /D -2 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE if not @FNAME=="""SO""" if not @FNAME=="
""SU""" echo @FILE"

"Class Pack"
"Oldies"
"WMI"

==>popd
```

Comment: I really appreciate it! It worked for me, but one question. What was I doing wrong with my original:                    
`if NOT @FNAME == %name%`

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit messy but I was able to do it on a local directory:

```
 @echo off

mkdir Temp\Temp

REM Copy all old file to Temp dir
forfiles -p "%cd%"  -m *.* /D -2 /C "cmd /c xcopy @path %cd%\Temp"

REM copy a random file from Temp dir to Temp/Temp dir and then delete it
FOR %%A in (%cd%\Temp\*) do (
   COPY "%%A"  %cd%\Temp\Temp\
   DEL "%%A"
   GOTO :Second
)
:Second

Rem copy second random file from Temp dir
FOR %%A in (%cd%\Temp\*) do (
   COPY "%%A"  %cd%\Temp\Temp\
   GOTO :Del
)
:Del

Rem delete all old files from local dir
forfiles -p "%cd%"  -m *.* /D -2 /C "cmd /c del @path"

Rem Copy back two random old files to local dir
xcopy %cd%\Temp\Temp\* %cd%

Rem remove Temp dir
rmdir /s /q Temp
```

Comment: Thanks so much! But I am working with 20Gb files I won't be able to copy, I was just looking for multiple conditions.